# Definition of Span Clarification

Tags: linear-algebra

Just a quick extract for context(most of you know should know this though):

"Let X be a subset of R^n. Then we define span X to be the smallest subspace of R^n which contains X. It is called the span of X."

Followed by a definition about linear combinations etc... of which I understand like the back of my hand. However; what actually does "define span X to be the **smallest subspace** of R^n" really mean? I can't seem to understand this, although I understand what span is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Smallest" means with respect to the partial order defined by inclusion.  That is, the span of $X$ is the linear subspace containing $X$ that does not properly contain another linear subspace also containing $X$.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, so if I were to describe it in my own words as; "having no repeated elements", that's fine?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "repeated elements?"

Comment: Sorry... For span X to be the smallest subspace of R^n to me right now means, a subspace defined using X, of which X has no repeated elements and X is linearly independent.

Comment: I must not be understanding because that is pretty much what a basis is right?

Comment: The definition you provided does not mention bases, for good reason (we do not want the definition to depend on a choice of basis).  Perhaps an example will illustrate the idea better.  Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the set $X=\{(1, 0), (\pi, 0)\}$.  Then the set $Y=\{(c, 0): c\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself are both linear subspaces containing $X$, but $\mathbb{R}^2$ properly contains $Y$, while $Y$ does not properly contain any subspace that contains $X$.  In other words, $Y$ is the smallest subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains $X$, i.e., $Y=\mathrm{span}(X)$.

Comment: Also, note that $X$ does not have to be a linearly independent set, as shown in the example that I gave above.  In particular, $X$ is not necessarily a basis for $\mathrm{span}(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

Span $X$ is defined as the space generated by elements of $X$. This space is a vector space and is the smallest subspace of $R^n$ containing $X$.

Comment: I know the definition, you didn't answer this question properly. I'm wondering what "define span X to be the smallest subspace of R^n" means.

Comment: These are equivalent definitions. I can provide a proof if you desire.

Comment: I can see this, but what do you mean by SMALLEST subspace? I'm asking what that actually means...

Comment: Any other subspace of $R^n$ that contains $X$ contains Span $X$.

Comment: You can think of spen of $(1,0) $ in $R^2$. Then this is just the line through zero with this direction. It is a subspace. There is no 'smaller' subspace in $R^2$ that contains all scalar multiples of this vector.